# RestSharp: Unable to deserialize array

Tags: c#, deserialization, restsharp

I am using RestSharp. I have the following code:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
       var client = new RestClient("https://test_site/api");
       var request = new RestRequest("/endpoint", Method.GET);

       var response = client.Execute<List<MyMapClass>>(request);
}
```

My problem is that in all the examples that I have seen, the JSON is in the form "property":"value".

However, in my case I just have an array of strings:

```
[
  "Str1",
  "Str2",
  "Str3"
]
```

So I know how to deserialize an object when the JSON is in the form "property":"value", but my question is: how can I deserialize an array of strings?

Comment: Just deserialize it to some kind of string collection (e.g. string array)?

Comment: How does `[ "Str1", "Str2", "Str3" ]` relate to `MyMapClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the square bracket rather than curly bracket.  The curly brackets represents an object, the square brackets represent an array.

```
var response = client.Execute<List<string>>(request);
```

Or

```
var response = client.Execute<string[]>(request);
```

You can also have an array in an object (see colors)

```
{
    "name": "iPhone 7 Plus",
    "manufacturer": "Apple",
    "deviceType": "smartphone_tablet",
    "searchKey": "apple_iphone_7_plus",
    "colors": ["red", "blue"]
}
```

and the corresponding model would look like this:

```
public class MyMapClass 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string DeviceType { get; set; }
    public string SearchKey { get; set; }
    public List<string> Colors { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How does this relate to what the OP is asking?

Comment: The OP seems to be confused between the differences between an array in JSON and an object.  This was an attempt to clarify the difference.  Feel free to add a better answer.

Comment: I couldn't offer an answer because the way I see it they are asking how to deserialize `[ "Str1", "Str2", "Str3" ]` into `MyMapClass`. It just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: OP explained they are learning from examples.  So I attempted to explain the differences between the examples rather than directly answering the question about deserializing a JSON array to a class, as I assume that’s not really what they are looking to do.  I could be wrong, will just have to see if OP responds...

Comment: @Enigmativity the way I read it (and I think how Shane read it) was that OP knows how to deserialize an object (_" all the examples that I have seen, the JSON is in the form "property":"value""_) but doesn't know how to construct a model for deserializing an array of strings (_"However, in my case **I just have an array of values** of variable size:"_).

Comment: @John - Yes, that's how I read it too. Their specific question was "So, in this case, how should the `MyMapClass` class be defined?" which is why I think that we must know how `[ "Str1", "Str2", "Str3" ]` maps to `MyMapClass` to be able to provide an answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity Oh, so you're thinking that the array should somehow map onto the properties of `MyMapClass`? I thought OP was using "MyMapClass" in lieu of the word "model". I see where you're coming from though. I guess we'll have to wait for clarification.

Comment: @John - Yes. It's the "somehow map" that I think we need to know.

Comment: @ShaneRay, @Enigmativity, @John - Yes, that's it. I know how to deserialize an object but doesn't know how to construct a model for deserializing an array of strings. So, according to the provided answer, I just need to have `client.Execute<List<string>>(request);` and I don't need to have a class to map the values. That resolves my problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @NunoF - Could you please add clarity to the question so that it is obvious to future readers?

Comment: @Enigmativity, I edited to add clarity to the question.